# Where does the EV3 software store its crash reports?

Tags: ev3, software

I cannot find where the crash reports generated by my EV3 software are stored. I have looked where it tells me to, but I can't find any.

Comment: What OS are you using (Windows/Mac)? And what is the path that it told you to look for?

Comment: Maybe the software never even crashed, that could be why.

Answer (score 2):

The location of the crash logs would depend on the system you are using. I have mapped out the three candidates below:

If you are using the classic **LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Education** software:

- Open your existing or a new experiment.
- Go to the *Tools* menu and select *Data Log File Manager*.
- Browse to the `.rdf` file and click the *Import* button. (It can be on the brick or on your computer.)
- If the directory is empty, there are no crash logs (yet)

If you are using **EV3 Python**, you are running through Visual Studio Code, and the crash handling will be done by VS.

On Windows, this would make the crash logs appear under `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`

If you are using **EV3 Classroom**

On Windows, this would make the crash logs appear under `%AppData%\LEGO\Mindstorms\Logs\`

On OSX, you can look for them at `/Applications/LEGO\MINDSTORMS\EV3\Home\Edition.app/Contents/MacOS/MindstormsEV3`

If you are using **some third party program**, the program provider should be able to advise you where logs are stored.